# How to read stdout from a subprocess when the latter does not flush its stdout?

Tags: c++, c, fork, pipe, stdout

Before the below code I do:

- create 1 pipe to read output from forked process
- fork()
- execv() a python script

Then in the parent process I do:

```
//set pipes to non-Blocking
File * cout_f = fdopen(cout_pipe[0], "r");
int flags = fcntl(cout_pipe[0], F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(cout_pipe[0], F_SETFL, flags|O_NONBLOCK);

// read from pipe and send it up through a callback method
int stat;
size_t size = 0;
char buffer [ 1000 ];
do
{
    while((size = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(char)*1000, cout_f))!=0)
    {
        call_back_function(buffer, size);
    }
}while(waitpid(child_pid, &stat, WNOHANG) != -1)

//Do 1 extra read
while((size = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(char)*1000, cout_f))!=0)
{
    call_back_function(buffer, size);
}
```

The problem I am facing happens when the child process prints to stdout and exits (normally) before flushing. I miss what was sent in the pipe.

Here are my questions:

- Is the above code safe/correct or can it be improved?
- Is there a way to read the entire pipe at the last moment when the subprocess dies, even if it doesn't flush its stdout?

Comment: As long the data isn't flushed, it's not written, thus no way!

Comment: Agreed! But as soon as the python sub-process dies, shouldn't the pipes be flushed automatically?

Comment: @Kam That depends how it died. If it exited normally, all its `stdio` buffers should be flushed. If it aborted, probably not.

Comment: Exactly, so I should be able to read all its stdout, but I don't! is there something missing in my code?

Comment: I don't see the point of setting the pipe into non-blocking mode. You aren't reading the error stream. You aren't reading until end of stream.

Comment: I use non-blocking fd, because I don't want to wait till the subprocess closes the pipe so I send the data through the callback method

Comment: You don't have to wait. Just send everything as you read it. That's what your code already does. Get rid of non-blocking mode; get rid of the while(wait(...)) condition; get rid of the final read; and just perform the first read loop until end of stream. Then call wait() to get the exit code.

Comment: Ow my god I never thought of that! Firstly: Does that solve my original question? Secondly: Can you put the above in a detailed answer please so I understand the implementation better?

Comment: It probably does, but if the process also produces on stderr you will need to read that in another thread, otherwise when the stderr buffer fills, it will block.

Comment: Ow you are correct, and I actually do real stderr. So can my issue be fixed with the above implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to wait. Just send everything as you read it. That's what your code already does. Get rid of non-blocking mode; get rid of the while(wait(...)) condition; get rid of the final read; and just perform the first read loop until end of stream. Then call wait() to get the exit code.

If the process also produces on stderr you will need to read that in another thread, otherwise when the stderr buffer fills, it will block.

Comment: Ow you are correct, and I actually do read stderr. So can my issue be fixed with the above implementation?

Comment: Or, if you do not want a second thread, you could use the select system call to wait until data is available on either pipe.

Comment: But what I don't get is the problem in the above code. I don't get what is wrong so I can fix it. Any idea?

Comment: @Kam You will read everything that got written and flushed this way. The problem with the above code is that there are too many problems with it, and I named several of them in comments.

Comment: +1 for 'get rid of non-blocking mode'; that is the key to the problem.